# Getting data for my financial dashboard with python

Tags: python

I want to calculate income of a commerce site  with services'sales and also products'sales  for financial dashboard with python.but I dont know how to get real data from the site.

Comment: Please provide detailed info so that answering your question becomes more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is that you want to get real-time data from your server(Database) to the Browser(Client), then leverage **WebSockets**. If you use Django on the backend, use **django Channels** and **Redis** to create WebSockets, and then connect to them using Javascript on the frontend. Refer to https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_1.html for a very simple practical implementation of this.

If you don't want bidirectional communication and more complexity, then you can also consider using **Server-Sent Events**. It is very useful when only unidirectional communication is required i.e. only one-sided communication from Server to the Browser(Client) is required. (Which is exactly what you want in this case, I think)